# Would Linux kernel send signal to the process when the process need to do swapping

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Recently, I was studying operating system. I have some questions about swapping process.

Due to finite physical memory restriction, I know that when we want to load a new program into physical memory, the kernel would not load entire program into physical memory.

Here is my question:

1. When a process met page fault, and the the process need to do swap in. Would the kernel deliver a signal to inform that process? If yes, what signal would the process receive?
2. Similar to first question, sometimes we want to load new program to physical memory. But, due to limit physical memory, we need to swap out some processes from the physical memory. Would the kernel deliver a signal to those processes which is going to be swapped out? If yes, what signal would those processed receive?

Any detailed explanation would be thankful.
I would also be grateful to you, if there is any useful link too.

Thanks for everyone for replying in advanced. :))

Comment: **1.** No; **2.** No. But if the kernel is out of memory (including swap space), it might kill some processes.

Comment: @lan Abbott, do you know why don't kernel deliver any signal to the process? Is it because of performance?

Comment: Because there is no need for such a signal. The process lives in a world of virtual memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are learning these concepts, I think you deserve a more-detailed answer. The OSs today present the abstraction of "virtual memory" (VM) to userspace applications. Essentially, its a n-bit virtual address space, where every page can be unmapped, or mapped with rwx permissions. Internally, the OS can change actual page permissions (see copy-on-write/deduplicated pages) or even not map them (demand paging). The condition is that userspace cannot see these, and whenever it accesses a mapped page with the correct permission, it (eventually) sees the correct data.

Swapping is one of the OS operations to bridge the gap between the abstraction (47-bit virtual memory) and reality (much smaller DRAM). As you have correctly pointed out, when DRAM is running short, the OS can temporarily move some pages to disk, and move them back when desired. Note that the VM abstraction is oblivious to this, and any OS swapping operations should be invisible to userspace. Therefore, the OS swaps-out pages (moves them to disk) and swaps-in pages (disk to ram) without telling userspace via signals.

To directly answer your questions:

1. None. Swapped-out pages are still expected to be legitimately mapped by userspace. The OS will hide the page-fault, swapping in the page and resuming the userspace process.
2. The OS will silently swap-out pages to reclaim memory, unless the memory shortage is so severe that it needs to kill processes. Btw, the kernel will try other ways to reclaim memory, like reducing the size of kernel buffers, before swapping-out user memory. In the common pages where no process is killed, no signals are sent out.

The reasons for abstraction are these: (i) it simplifies application development, (ii) applications run the same across different hardware platforms, (iii) new features added by the OS does **not** make applications obsolete.

The above is a simplification: the kernel does provide an API for programs to manage their own memory ([see this](https://lwn.net/Articles/550555/)). This API is useful for programs like databases and browsers who want to implement their own swapping policies, due to application-specific access patterns and performance requirements.

Comment: Hi @TSG, many thanks for your detailed explanation !!

According to your explanation, can I assume that the reason why OS would not send any signal (when doing swapping-in / swapping-out) to process, is because that we want the process still have the "illusion" that it still have those page in memory, right?

Comment: Besides, is it for the sake of performance, so that we want those operations be invisible to userspace?

Comment: If we modified OS, and force sending signal to process when doing those operations. Would the perfomance of OS be cut severely?

Comment: Computer-systems are often built on the principle of abstraction, which presents a consistent view while hiding implementation details. The main reason why the OS hides these operations from userspace is for the sake of abstraction. This significantly simplifies the application developer's job in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: When writing a "hello world" program, or when writing a pdf reader (for example), the application developer can just assume a simple, infinite virtual-address space, and not have to think of various OS mechanisms which affect real page allocation: paging/swapping, demand paging, transparent hugepages, COW pages, file-backed pages, and more. Further, if the OS implements a new optimization, the user does not have to change their program to handle a new signal, it is all transparently handled.

Comment: Certain simple kernels (or microkernels) might notify userspace on faults, but performance is typically not the main reason. They just have different abstractions.

Comment: thanks again for your detailed explanation. You made my day!!